# How to submit blog entries to facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-like

I want to submit my blog entries to my wall on facebook.  For the Like button code you have to provide a URL for the page you want shared on facebook.  But each of my blog entries has a unique, dynamically generated, URL and I would like to post each blog entry vs the entire blog page to facebook.  The Like button code looks like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mysite.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I'm usring Rails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `data-href` attribute provided within the *Facebook Like* div and put there the unique link to your blog post.

I'm not sure how your code is written but I may guess that smth like this will give you a lead:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<%= post_url(@post) %>" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```